# Phalconphp: Getting router parameters outside of Controller

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I have a router defined like this

```php
$router->add("/api/:controller/:action/:params", array(
    'controller' => 1,
    'action' => 2,
    'params' => 3,
    'myParameter' => 'test'
));
```

So, I can get that "myParameter" parameter inside of controller like this

```php
$this->dispatcher->getParam("myParameter");
```

But, I want to use this parameter in another class I call from Controller. Something like

```
myCustomClass::test();


class myCustomClass {
    function test() {
        // this is where I need that parameter
    }
}
```

Dispatcher returns nothing if I call it from `myCustomClass`.

(Of course getting the value inside of controller and passing it as a value is a solution, but I will probably use it at least for 100 different actions, so it is not really a good solution in this case).

Is there a way of getting that extra parameter outside of the scope of controller.

Answer (score 1):

You need Default Dependency Injection, probably declared in index.php.

```
class myCustomClass {
    static function test() {
        $request = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->get( 'request' );
        $request->get("myParameter");
    }
}
```

Also you are missing STATIC word from function.

Comment: (sorry, I already had static in my code, forgot to paste it here), but still this one is giving me no result.  Same behaviour with the shivanshupatel's answer.

Comment: seems proper but I have strange feeling: shouldn't it be from `dispatcher` instead of `request`?

Comment: @yergo dispatcher control application flow, controller sequencing. Request accesses information from URL, GET, POST and others.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but I think you access get parameters from phalcon Http request class.

```
$request = new Phalcon\Http\Request();
$request->get("myParameter");
```

Comment: tried that, it returns the actual request params (get and post). For this url, '/api/user/profile/1?x=y&a=b' $request->get() is Array ( [_url] => /api/user/profile/1 [x] => y [a] => b )